# Multilayered Bi-Directional Encoder for Seq2Seq in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement multilayered Bi-Directional Encoder for Seq2Seq.

What I am doing now is following :

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_size) 
cell = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw =encoder_cell, cell_bw =encoder_cell, .... )
```

This creates a bidirectional rnn but how to make it multilayered ?

What I am trying to achieve is following architecture, where each LSTM block is bidirectional and output of nth layer encoder goes into nth layer decoder.

[image]

I am using Tensorflow 1.0 and using **`tf.contrib.seq2seq`** library for decoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as simple as:

tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell for _ in range(num_layers)])

Note that everything is called a cell in this context (which is a very bad naming), including a real single neural unit, a layer, and multiple layers. Try to avoid * operation for the creation of multiple layers (for future compatibility) as explained in the release notes of version 1.2 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases).

Comment: cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_size) 
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell for _ in range(num_layers)])

Are you suggesting to use this cell in bidirectional_dynamic_rnn function ? 

MultiRnnCell only returns output of last layer. But decoder needs output_state of each layer of encoder, right ? How to achieve that ?

Comment: MultiRNNCell returns a list of cells (layers), each of which is having the same network architecture as specified by the giving cell parameter. You can read the release notes I quoted for details.

Comment: Is it for TF 1.0 also ? I am using that

Comment: The for loop works for all releases, and it will generate the same result. If you use *, it may work for 1.0 in one way, but may generate different result when you upgrade your TensorFlow in the future.

Comment: I created a multiRNNCell and used this in my bidirectional_dynamic_rnn. It returned the fw_states and bw_states for all layers, which after concatenating I passed to multilayered decoder, tf.contrib.rnn.dynamic_rnn_decoder . But it flagged an error that it expected two dimensional encoder_states, but since my encoder here is multilayered it will return encoder states for all layers.

Comment: Would really appreciate if you can respond to this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498771/multilayer-encoder-output-state-to-multilayer-decoder-in-seq2seq-model-tf-1-0

Comment: Just want to mention, the answer given by me was not clear enough. Actually, if you use version 1.2, it will warn you if you use the cell variable (returned by a function) instead of using the function itself. In order to use different weights for each layer, you need to replace cell in [cell for _ in range(num_layers)] by a function so that it looks like: [create_cell(num_units)  for _ in range(num_layers)].